# Saga GIS Snap Points to Lines tool doesn't produce required results

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, saga, snapping

I have two sets of data that I'm using. Points extracted from a .csv file and a road network from an ESRI .shp file (both of which I've included here: https://send.firefox.com/download/6f08f9e4938fb389/#Kl20O__Px_D9NP6KcqLu5Q | Password: qgis123). I need to snap each point to its nearest road segment and get the result as a separate point layer.

I am using QGIS 3.8.1 Zanzibar and for the above task I've decided to use the SAGA GIS **Snap Points to Lines** tool available in the QGIS processing toolbox.

However, after running the algorithm, as an output I get the same point layer that I started off with without any snapping as the result.

What am I doing wrong?

---

In addition to this, can you advise me as to where I might find the source file for the SAGA Snap Points to Lines tool?